# MVC 3 Bootstrap Time Picker Always Show Current Time on Edit view

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I have a MVC 3 project in which I am using Bootstrap Jquery Timepicker control for the input of two fields.

The C# datatype for the corresponding view model and entity model properties is "DateTime?" and the datatype for the corresponding Database field is time.

When I am on the Create view everything works as expected. The field starts blank on Create and when I hit save it goes all the way fine to the database. On Details view the value is being shown correct.  The only issue I have in both view is the format.  Say for example 9:45 am, Create view shows it like 9:45 AM and Details view shows it like 9:45:00 a.m.  I would like to show the same format in both but if not possible I can live with that.

The real issue comes in Edit view, when entering Edit view both fields show current time instead of showing the time that has been saved to database. And thats very weird. I have other parts of the project where I use Bootstrap Jquery Datepicker and Bootstrap Jquery Datetimepicker and every thing is fine. But in this view where i need the Bootstrap Jquery Timepicker I have this weird issue.

Here are some pieces of code that are related to the fields involved.

View model properties

```
[DataType(DataType.Time)]
[Display(Name = "Start time")]
public DateTime? startTime { get; set; }

[DataType(DataType.Time)]
[Display(Name = "End time")]
public DateTime? endTime { get; set; }
```

Piece of code where data is extracted from SqlDataReader to entity class.

```
else if (row["ColumnName"].ToString() == "StartTime")
{
    if (!readCursor.IsDBNull(idx))
    {
        TimeSpan startTime = readCursor.GetTimeSpan(idx);
        item.startTime = item.doneDate.Value + startTime;
    }
}
else if (row["ColumnName"].ToString() == "EndTime")
{
    if (!readCursor.IsDBNull(idx))
    {
        TimeSpan endTime = readCursor.GetTimeSpan(idx);
        item.endTime = item.doneDate.Value + endTime;
    }
}
```

Jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("tr.editor-table-row input[name$='.startTime'], tr.editor-table-row input[name$='.endTime']").each(function () {
        $(this).timepicker({
        });
    });
});
```

I hope anyone can give me some lights on solving this issue. My guess is maybe time format 9:45:00 a.m. is not compatible with time picker format 9:45 AM.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If your sql type is `time`, then you model property should be `TimeSpan`, not `DateTime`

Comment: Have you by any little chance missed to assign DB values to your Model properties in case of Edit view?

Comment: It sounds like there are two issues here: 1 - inconsistent format of time b/w Create & Detail views.  2 - Edit view is getting set to current time instead of time from DB.  Can you post your edit & detail views?

Comment: Hi Stephen Mueckle, thanks for the reply.  Indeed I tried with TimeSpan but had more problems thats why I decided to use DateTime and do the conversion.
        TimeSpan endTime = readCursor.GetTimeSpan(idx);
        item.endTime = item.doneDate.Value + endTime;

Comment: Hi slashNburn, indeed the format thing is what I think is making noise.  Right now I am not in the computer where I have the code. I will post it when I get to the computer. You need model and view or just view?

Comment: Hi RRM, the DB are correctly assigned to model classes. If I remove the jquery code that creates the timepicker the screen shows a text input with the DB value.